# Scala match both String and Array

Tags: arrays, string, scala, match

I am trying to call the method [foldLeft](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.html#foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB):B) on String/Array object. Something like:

```
def doSth(obj: Any): Int = {
  obj match {
    case t: TraversableOnce[Any] => t.foldLeft(0)((rs: Int, i: Any) => ...)
    case other => ...
  }
}
```

but when I call `doSth("abc")`, it matches `case other`. What I want is `case t: TraversableOnce[Any]`.

Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Of course `Array` is not `TraversableOnce` either, it can only be converted to it, just like `String`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String is not a sub type of TraversableOnce. That's why It will not match TraversableOnce.

Although String can be implicitly convert to StringOps which is a sub type of TraversableOnce. check `Predef.augmentString`

You can do like this. In this case scala compiler will implicitly convert `String` to `StringOps`. It will print out `class scala.collection.immutable.StringOps` if we pass in a `"hello"`

```
def doSth(obj: TraversableOnce[Any]): Int = {
    println(obj.getClass())
    obj.foldLeft(0)((rs: Int, i: Any) => ...)
}
```

And in the following code. It will print out `class java.lang.String` if we pass in a `"hello"`. Which means there is no implicit conversion.

```
def doSth(obj: Any): Int = {
  obj match {
    case t: TraversableOnce[Any] => t.foldLeft(0)((rs: Int, i: Any) => ...)
    case other => 
      println(other.getClass)
  }
}
```

Comment: So in match/case, scala will not try to implicitly convert to StringOps?

Comment: You could;
`case t: String => { val x: TraversableOnce[Any] = t; doSth(x)`}